# What does this mean in SVN? - Error writing to '.'

Tags: linux, svn, unix

```
svn up
svn: Error writing to '.'
svn: Can't write to file '.svn/tmp/entries': No space left on device
```

If my box is out of hard drive space, that is impossible, because it has 620GB of HD.

Comment: In addition to `df -h`, run `df -i` and tell us your inode usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably don't have space on the disk where is the svn tree. What is output of `df .` in that directory?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your hard disk is partitioned. Check the partition that svn is trying to write on for the amount of available space.

If you are 100% sure you have space left, try `quota` to see whether you have exceeded the quota for your user account.

Answer (score 0):

That may be, but how is your drive partitioned and what folders mount where on your paratitions. Do a "df -h" at the command line to see... and then decide.